# Startup Directory

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

Im developing java program ,and I need to make it start working at each reboot for user pc.How I can find the Startup directory path to place batch.bat file into it independently form the operating system used at user pc ?

Correct my question:

Im developing java program ,and I need to make it start working at each reboot for user pc.How I can do that at different platforms ?

Comment: Independently of the operating system? Windows is the only operating system supporting `.bat` files and having a Startup directory.

Comment: also the startup directory path defer between Windows XP and Winows 7.then How i can make it start at reboot of PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to determine which OS is used and place your application accordingly

Win7:

```
%systemdrive%\users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

Comment: yes and for Windows XP :
%userprofile%\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
what about Linux and iMac

Comment: and I emphasise, that Linux and MacOS will not support .bat files.

Comment: then how i should deal with them , for my need to launch my program at start up of Linux and MacOS PCs

Comment: first: http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-get-example/get-OS-name.shtml
Linux:  have a look at https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/how-to-add-a-program-to-linux-startup-683818/
MacOS:  http://forums.appleinsider.com/t/8942/adding-programs-to-osx-startup

Answer (score 0):

You could make life easier by using the registry for any Windows platforms, this is the same in all versions from at least XP.

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

I'm not sure about other OS's though.